# Change names in rows of gt table

Tags: r, gt

I am making a table with `gt` and I'm looking to be able to change the values of certain rows.

```
library(gt)

row1<- "row1"
row2<- "row2"

rows<- rbind(row1, row2)

column1<- c(1,2)

frame<- as.data.frame(cbind(rows, column1))

gt(frame)
```

I'm hoping to change 'row1' and 'row2' to *row*_1 and *row*_2, with the underscores representing subscripts. I've gone through the options in `tab_options` and `fmt` but haven't found anything useful. All of the resources I've found show how to relabel columns instead of rows.

Since the row names are the names of the objects included in the table, I could just change the names of the objects, but that does not let me italicize/add subscripts or spaces between the words I'm hoping to use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If rows are really the important feature (which they sometimes are), one option is to use `gsub()` + `group_by()`.

To make sure we're on the same page, say you have a dataset that is something like:

```
landscape <- c("plain", "forest", "jungle", "mountains")
danger_score <- c(2, 3, 4, 3)
beauty_score <- c(2, 3, 3, 4)
d_land <- cbind(landscape, danger_score, beauty_score)
d_land <- as.data.table(d_land) # I tend to like data.table
d_land <- melt(d_land, id.vars = "landscape")
```

Which gives you something like

```
   landscape     variable value
1:     plain danger_score     2
2:    forest danger_score     3
3:    jungle danger_score     4
4: mountains danger_score     3
5:     plain beauty_score     2
6:    forest beauty_score     3
7:    jungle beauty_score     3
8: mountains beauty_score     4
```

Which is just fine, but won't look like a beautiful table.

Since the `gt` package can be used with pipes and `dplyr` commands, you can use

```
d_land %>%
  group_by(landscape, variable) %>%
  gt()
```

to create a table with two row groups. However, the row groups under `variable` will have the headers "danger_score" and "beauty_score".

To deal with this, I just use gsub on `variable` before putting the dataset through the `gt()` command.

```
tab2.1$variable <- gsub("beauty_score", "Beauty Score", tab2.1$variable)
tab2.1$variable <- gsub("danger_score", "Danger Score", tab2.1$variable)
```

And that will take care of your row groups in a way that allows you to get around putting spaces and other touchy characters in the column names. There is also the `tab_row_group()` function (in the [documentation](https://mpn.metworx.com/packages/gt/0.2.2/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html)), but there you have to explicitly specify the row group names and their members, which beyond being more work, can be cumbersome when using a double row index.

It really depends on your data and your preferences, but that's what worked for me.

Comment: Actually, I don't recommend this method if you're working with more than one row group. I ended up using the `tables` package instead. You can just use tabular(var1*var2 ~ columns, data) with gsub() as mentioned above to get alternating row groups that are much more aesthetically pleasing.